# Create form in frontend in a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, form

Am creating a simple custom search , where users will search using a droplist of option , i have successfully created the module , however i do not know how to show the form in frontend and how to pass values to my helper file for validation , please help ! Below is my code

**model(helper.php)**

```
public static function getdata($catid)
    {
          //$catid1=17;
           $res=array();
           $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
           $cat = $categories->get($catid);
           $children = $cat->getChildren();
           $res['FieldofStudy']=$children;

        return $res;
    }
```

**View (tmpl/default.php)**
 Which is form that shows droplist to send back to controller

```
            <select id="Field-of-Study" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach($res['FieldofStudy'] as $a){  ?>
                <option>
                <?php  echo $a->title ;  ?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
```

Comment: Please show some code. I assume you have already created the HTML markup for the form right?

Comment: @Lodder see new edit with code

Comment: @Lodder or should i use xml file in tmpl folder to define form as in plugin development ?

Comment: I'm writing my answer now. 2 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do it like this:

Lets say you have a few form fields (for example, 2 inputs and a select box):

```
<form method="post" name="shout">

    <input name="myform[name]" type="text">

    <input name="myform[surname]" type="text">

    <select name="myform[study]" id="Field-of-Study" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach($res['FieldofStudy'] as $a) : ?>
            <option><?php echo $a->title; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

</form>
```

Notice I've used `myform` in the `name=""` attribute.

Now, in your **mod_mymodule.php** file, you can check if the post if set and get the entire post array from your form like so:

```
if (isset($_POST))
{
    $post = $app->input->post->get('myform', array(), 'array');

    // You can now access each field value using
    // $post['name']
    // $post['surname']
    // $post['study']
}
```

To put the post into a function in the **helper.php**, you first need to call the helper like so:

```
$helper = new ModMYMODULEHelper();
```

Then call the function from the helper

```
$helper->myfunction($post);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @jimmyobonyo - You're welcome ;)

Comment: Just one more thing , lets say i get the fillterd values in the helper file , and i want this values to be displayed in another the main page ie not the modules view how would i go about this please

Comment: You mean somewhere else on the site? in which case, I'd most likely use `JSession` and push the value to a session. For a more in-depth answer, I'd suggest asking a new question though

Comment: No not somewhere else but , lets say the form is floated left in the page , i want to display the form in main page view ie the center page

Comment: Oh I see. You can assigned your module a custom position, then in an article, use `{loadposition MYPOSITION}` to call your module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33380/discussion-between-jimmy-obonyo-and-lodder).